# Como juntar os arrays por ordem crescente com array unique

Tags: php

Bom é o seguinte eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "BMW", "Ferrari");
$cars2 = array_unique($cars);

echo $cars2[0];
echo "<br><br>";
echo $cars2[1];
echo "<br><br>";
echo $cars2[2];
echo "<br><br>";
echo $cars2[3];
```

Eu ao mostrar o `$cars2[3],` mostra-me um erro, mas na teoria eu queria que me mostrasse o Ferrari, ou seja como posso fazer para juntar os *arrays*, excluindo os repetidos, e que os *arrays* tenham sempre resultado.

Como poderei fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$cars  = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "BMW", "Ferrari");
$cars2 = array_unique($cars);
$cars2 = array_values($cars2);

print_r($cars2);
```

Comment: Penso que seja isso, mas a ordem fica toda trocada? Como posso fazer isso de forma que fique com a ordem correta?

Comment: Editei, veja agora.

Comment: Perfeito! Muito Obrigado pela ajuda.